# AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR when loading a remote Image in SIlverlight

Tags: silverlight, image, cross-domain

I have a `ListBox` that gets populated with items read from a JSON response. Each item has an `Image` control that displays the thumbnail at the remote URL given by the `Thumbnail` property. I created a custom `IValueConverter` to convert the URL to a `BitmapImage`, but the image still didn't display. So I finally realized that I could capture loading errors with the `ImageFailed` event.

What I get is an **AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR**. I looked at Silverlight's [URL Access Restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008(VS.95).aspx) and the table states that loading an `Image` from another domain is allowed without a **crossdomain.xml** file.

I'm positive that the URL is valid and points to an image, because I can copy and paste it directly from the JSON and view it in a browser. Yet, Silverlight refuses to load it.

Why is this?

**EDIT:** I installed Fiddler, which does show requests being made when the Silverlight page is loaded. None of these requests are for the image, however. It appears that Silverlight isn't even attempting to make a request and automatically throwing the exception.

Comment: What happens if you add the image hosting domain to the crossdomain.xml file anyway?

Comment: I don't have any control over the crossdomain.xml file.

Comment: Mike Snow he wrote a small piece of code to get to the cause of AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR. Maybe that'll help you identify the problem. You can find it on http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2009/01/27/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-88-how-to-handle-image-ag-e-network-error-errors.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned in my question that I'm already using the ImageFailed event, which is how I'm seeing the AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR. And that's all it says. There's no error code to explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone answered this on the Silverlight forums. The problem turned out to be that I was using the auto-generated debug page, instead of an IIS website. Silverlight doesn't allow cross-protocol calls (in this case, from file:// to http://).

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually trying to download the image (binary content) using WebClient or another HTTP stack in Silverlight? Unless you can write that cross domain file, this is not possible.

I believe you must just set the URL of the Image.Source, which then would let Silverlight resolve the image. You would also see Fiddler make the request at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

1. Add de Web project in order to have your own development server.
2. Set it as startup project.
3. Open its properties. Web tab: mark specific page.
4. Web tab / Debuggers (at the bottom): mark Silverlight.

Now you can run & debug your Silverlight application without installing an ISS Server.