# ag_e_network_error when loading image in Windows store app

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm having some problem which should be quite a simple task, loading an image in a Windows store app from a URL. My code is as follows:

```
  Image image = new Image();
  image.Stretch = Stretch.None;
  image.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
  BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
  image.Source = bitmap;
  bitmap.ImageFailed += bitmap_ImageFailed;
  panel.Children.Add(image);
  scroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(Double.MaxValue);
```

Only sometimes when I load the image I get an ImageFailed event with the error AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR for no apparent reason. The image is stored in Azure Blob Storage and accessible via a URL. I know this works fine.

The url of the image I require is being sent via a web request from an ASP.NET Web API role.

The problem seems to occur intermittently when I first make the local web request to an instance of the Web api hosted locally (localhost) which gives me the image url and then get the image via the given url from azure blob storage.

It doesn't seem to follow any distinct pattern and has left me rather confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793487/ag-e-network-error-when-loading-a-remote-image-in-silverlight) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=ag_e_network_error)?

I suspect that you are using `BitmapImage` with URL, that's may be causing problem. Try to use `HttpClient` and let me know if it works or not ?

Comment: thanks, it appears to have stopped for some reason. Using HTTP Client works every time though so thanks